# Accessing elements of array based on indices given by another array

Tags: arrays, indexing, julia

Suppose I have the following `4x4 Array` in Julia:

```
julia> A=rand(4,4)
4×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.00624508  0.624399  0.458094  0.341848
 0.303817    0.269487  0.580949  0.534655
 0.748525    0.419411  0.469938  0.659914
 0.730659    0.191461  0.996144  0.74772
```

And I have another `6x2 Array` where each row represents a row-column pair:

```
julia> B=[ 1 1; 1 3; 2 2; 2 4; 3 1; 3 3]
6×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1
 1  3
 2  2
 2  4
 3  1
 3  3
```

The first row of `B` represents the element `[1,1]` of `A`, the second row of `B` represents the element `[1,3]` of `A`, and so on. I want to access the elements of `A` based on the coordinates given by each row of `B`. In `R` for example, the command `A[B]` gives exactly what I want: `0.00624508 0.458094 0.269487 0.534655 0.748525 0.469938` but in Julia, the same command gives

```
julia> A[B]
6×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.00624508  0.00624508
 0.00624508  0.748525
 0.303817    0.303817
 0.303817    0.730659
 0.748525    0.00624508
 0.748525    0.748525
```

and this is not what I want. Is there a similar way of coding `A[B]` in Julia, so that I obtain what I obtain in `R`? Must be applicable to any Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct an array of [`CartesianIndex`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Cartesian-indices-1) out of your index pairs:

```
julia> A[CartesianIndex.(B[:, 1], B[:, 2])]
6-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.987200021334854    
 0.5261639427155012   
 0.8430528192705655   
 0.5300778835366697   
 0.5044387593056074   
 0.0025132074927423087
```

This is necessary to distinguish such "point indexing" from "shape indexing", as you observed it (I made those terms up).

Ideally, you would already construct `B` as such an array, but that is not always feasible, of course.

Comment: Oh I see! The secret was the `CartesianIndex` ! I was reading the Julia webpage concerning indexing and saw it but didn't see how I could use it. Thank you!